# OMP Task Race Condition? Valid replacement for locks?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, task, openmp, race-condition

Trying to queue two tasks in sequential order based on conditions being met. Basically, task1 must complete before task2 is queued. Is the code below a valid way to achieve this? Assume at least 3 threads are being used. bTask1 and bTask2 are only there for the sake of exiting the while loop. I'm more interested in whether val causes a race condition or is a valid way to replace the use of locks. If it isn't, what's a minimal way of using OMP locking mechanisms to have task1 and task2 performed in order? In a realistic case, I would have a bunch of parallel tasks that need to be performed in a certain order (ie. asynchronous tree traversal from leaves to root).

EDIT: The code below winds up in an infinite loop. Anyone know why?

EDIT2: Code works with O0 but not O3 optimization. Confirmed that O0 still produces multithreading behavior. I don't like where this is going :(

```
    int val = 0;
    bool bTask1 = true, bTask2 = true;
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(cout, bTask1, bTask2, val) num_threads(4)
    {

#pragma omp single nowait 
        {
            while(bTask1) {
                if(val == 0) {
                    val = -1;
#pragma omp task shared(cout, val, bTask1)
                    {
                        cout << "Hello from task 1" << endl;
                        val = -2;
                        bTask1 = false;
                    }
                }
                //                cout << "1" << endl;
            }
        }

#pragma omp single nowait 
        {
            while(bTask2) {
                if(val == -2) {
                    val = -3;
#pragma omp task shared(cout, val, bTask2)
                    {
                        cout << "Hello from task 2" << endl;
                        val = -4;
                        bTask2 = false;                     
                    }       
                }
                //                cout << "2" << endl;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Read the standard on task dependencies... they are designed to enable constraints like the one you want to express!

Comment: @JimCownie interesting. did not know about the depends keywords. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with OpenMP 3.0. What's my alternative?

Comment: "I am stuck with OpenMP 3.0" Why? You need to question this! Otherwise, the obvious answer is to have task1 create task2 once it has finished, or, simply merge the two tasks (since there is no parallelism between them that's fine from a performance POV). Since your example shows your attempted solution it's impossible to guess what your real code (and therefore problem) looks like, so it's hard to go beyond that!  (Which is really to say that you may be trying to solve the wrong problem, but we can't tell)